# Сравнение структуры двух каталогов

Tags: bat, дерево

Я столкнулся с задачей, которая звучит так:

> Создать командный файл, позволяющий сравнить структуру двух указанных каталогов

Конкретней: у нас есть два каталога, которые мы задаём параметрами. Их мы сравниваем БЕЗ учёта имен подкаталогов.
Пример:

```
Tree /a 1

        +---BA
        |   +---K
        |   |   \---DO
        |   |       +---C
        |   |       \---S
        |   \---T
        \---DO
            +---C
            \---S
```

```
Tree /a 2

        +---A                                                                                                          
        |   +---C                                                                                              
        |   \---O                                                                                              
        |       \---D                                                                                          
        |           +---C                                                                                      
        |           \---S                                                                                      
        \---F                                                                                                      
            +---N                                                                                                  
            \---V
```

Cуть в том, что оба каталога имеют одинаковую структуру и вывод результата об их сравнении должен говорить, что они идентичный. Однако Tree при выводе структуры каталога 2, использует вывод в соответствии с алфавитным порядком, потому даже если мы попробуем сравнить файлы содержащие, условно, только "скелеты" деревьев, без имён файлов через fc или comp, нам скажут, что файлы разные и структура соответственно не идентична, поэтому даже так мы имеем зависимость от имён подкаталогов. Получается, что использование дерева никак не помогает решению.

Есть ли у вас другие идеи для решения данной задачи?